# Using jquery how to refresh the contents of .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code

```
 window.onload = function () {

        var startup = '@ViewBag.site';

        var url = '@Url.Action("data_type_partial", "HistorySite", new { sitename = "java_get"})'
        var url = url.replace("java_get", startup);

        $("#loader").load(url);
    };


    function change(val) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("data_type_partial", "HistorySite", new { sitename = "java_get"})'
        var url = url.replace("java_get", val);

        $("#loader").load(url);
      }
```

On windows startup I am using `.load()` to load a partial view into `#loader div`. 
After i click a button to call `change()` function,the `#loader` `div` should then change to the new `.load(url)`.The problem is that when i click on the button it doesn't change to the new `.load()` but stays the same

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your button code?

Comment: put a `console.log()` into your `change()` function and see if it enters the function

Comment: function change() {} is the button code. And this does run but it doesn't refresh the #loader for the new .load()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the url that you're calling is cached before!

Check if it's where cached, replace this with your "change" function:

```
    function change(val) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("data_type_partial", "HistorySite", new { sitename = "java_get"})'
    var url = url.replace("java_get", val);

    $("#loader").load(url + '?noCache=' + (new Date).getTime() );
  }
```

This will prevent from cashing.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't do what I wanted.it didn't replace the current  .load() content with the new .load() unfortunately